# How to animate nestedscrollview to bottom

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to expand a collapse tool bar. I can right now collapse the tool bar when I release my Nestedscrollview and It is almost colapsed. The problem is, I don't know how to animate the expansion the I release it almost expanded.

Here is my code:

```
nestedScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.d("Touch", "Toque down");

                        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
                        AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
                        if (behavior != null) {
                            Log.d("Touch", "Behavior chamado");
                            if(isCompressed) {
                                behavior.onNestedFling(coordinatorLayout, appBarLayout, null, 0, 10000, true);
                            } else{
                               //How can I make it go down??
                            }
                        }

                        return false;
                }

                Log.d("Touch", "Toque");
                return false;
            }
```

This code makes my bar to colapse when it is almost collapsed... **How can I make it scroll down when it is almost expanded?**

Comment: Have you checked this out ? : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.Behavior.html

Comment: Well, yes. This what I am using right now... But I am only able to scroll up

Comment: I read the refenrence on android developper, it seems you have to use 'onStartNestedScroll' before using 'onNestedFling'

Comment: Did my answer work for you ? If it did, please mark it as is.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should do:

```
NestedScrollView nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.your_nested_scroll_view);

int toolbarHeight = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar).getHeight();

nestedScrollView.startNestedScroll(ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL);
nestedScrollView.dispatchNestedPreScroll(0, toolbarHeight, null, null);
nestedScrollView.dispatchNestedScroll(0, 0, 0, 0, new int[]{0, -toolbarHeight});
nestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, nestedScrollView.getBottom());
```

Or you could use:

```
nestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
nestedScrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
```